# [object Object]undefined on input form (jquery+json+php)

Tags: jquery, json, object, each

can someone help me displaying that JSON array

> {"contenusModeleCarte"{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte0":"pommes au four
>   "},{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte1":"salade de
>   fruits"},{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte2":"bananes"}]}

into form inputs.

When I try to do it via this code

```
$.each(dataModeleCarte.contenusModeleCarte, function(i,contenusModeleCarte){
  if(contenusModeleCarte.dessertCarte+i == null){
     $("#edit-field-dessert-carte-"+ i +"-value-field-dessert-value").val('');
  }else{
     $("#edit-field-dessert-carte-"+ i +"-value-field-dessert-value").val(contenusModeleCarte.dessertCarte);
  }
});
```

I only get as a result :

> [object Object]undefined

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "dessertCarte" in the JSON has the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... after it, so it can't find a `contenusModeleCarte.dessertCarte`

You need to append the index `i` after "dessertCarte":

```
 .val(contenusModeleCarte["dessertCarte" + i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Is that the entire JSON string?  If it is, one issue is you are missing the first colon and square bracket.  It should read:

> {"contenusModeleCarte":[{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte0":"pommes au four
>   "},{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte1":"salade de
>   fruits"},{"idmodele":"65","modeleName":"","typerepas":null,"commentairesModeleCarte":"premier
>   commentaire pour le premier modele de
>   carte","dessertCarte2":"bananes"}]}